# Using document.write in event handler?

Tags: javascript, html

I am experimenting with HTML and JavaScript. The following code should print something when entering a keystroke in a textbox:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="commandInput" name="command" size="50" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var commandInput = document.getElementById("commandInput");
            commandInput.onkeydown = function (evt) {
                document.writeln("Test");
            };
        </script>    

    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason the textbox disappears when entering a keystroke, leaving nothing but a white page.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `document.write` or `document.writeln` after the page has loaded. Calling it after the page has loaded (in Firefox, at least) does an automatic call to `document.open()`, which wipes out the current document.

If you're using it as a debugging tool, I'd suggest using Firebug and `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative method, using .innerHTML to insert text in an element.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="commandInput" name="command" size="50" />
        <div id="text"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var commandInput = document.getElementById("commandInput");
            commandInput.onkeydown = function () {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Testing...";
            };
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try onkeyup, instead, so that it takes the most recent input into the new field.

On a sidenote, toss this into a new.html and check it out, may interest you if you're just fooling around, as it comes up with a pretty cool effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>onkeyup</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFocus(){
        document.theForm.command.focus();   
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">
<form id="theForm">
<input type="text" id="commandInput" name="command" size="50" style="font-size:20px; color:gray; font-family:arial; border:0 none; opacity:0.4" />
        <div id="text" style="position:absolute; float:left; margin-left:3px; margin-top:-26px; font-size:20px; font-family:arial; color:black;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var commandInput = document.getElementById("commandInput");
            commandInput.onkeyup = function () {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=commandInput.value;
            };
        </script>   
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

When you load the page, hit Tab and start typing.